# Who is the king of Paathal lok? Bali or Mahiravan?

Tags: vishnu, gods, avatars

We know that Vaman avatar is before Ram avatar.

If Bali is king of Paathal lok then who will be Mahi Ravan who ruled Paathal lok during Ramayan?

i.e. Bali is temporary king?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bali is temporary king?
```

No, Mairavana was the king of Patala loka. While, Bali is the king of Sutala loka.

The referances in scriptures are as follows,

Parashar Samhita,
45th chapter, anecdote of entry of Hanuman in Patal,

> अस्ति**पाताल**लंकायां मैरावणपुरं महत्
> देवदानव दुर्धर्षम् सप्तप्रकार वेष्टितम्।।

Vibhishan explaining Hanuman about Mairavanpur in **Patala** says it has 7 barriers which are protected in such a way, that it is difficult to explain even by Devas & Asuras.

Vamana Puran, the blessings to Bali,

> सुतलं नाम पातालमधस्ताद् वसुधातलात्।
> बलेर्दत्तं भगवत्ता विष्णुना प्रभविष्णुना।।
> The mighty Vishnu, gave the **Patala named Sutal** to Bali (to rule & blessed him to be next Indra)

Now, actually people consider any realm below earth as Patal. Thus the confusion has arrised.

Actually, Sutal loka is the 3rd realm below earth, while patala is 7th loka below earth.
This is expalined by Narayana in the
Devi bhagwata Mahapuran, 8th Skanda, 18 chapter,On the narrative of Rāhu Maṇḍalam.

Narayana said,

> O Devarṣi! At the lower part of this earth there are seven places (caves or nether regions). Their diameter is one Ayuta Yoyanas. In all the seasons, all sorts of enjoyments can be had at these places. The first is **Atala**; the second is **Vitala**.
> Next come in order :-- **Sutala, Talātala, Mahātala. Rasātala, and lastly (the seventh) the Pātāla**.

Thus, after Mairavan died, Srī Rām crowned Makardhwaja as the king of Patala. While, Bali will rule Sutal loka till the end of this Manvantar & become next Indra.

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Comment: You have written that Bali will become next Indra but I have heard that Bali becoming the next Indra is puranic and not vedic. Indra is also described as parabrahma and is not a position in Vedas. Is this true?

Comment: @LSSJBroly I haven't read Vedas, since I have no Yagnopavit. But, to wht u said Indra **deemed** as Parbrahama is true. But Indra indeed is position, becoz Puranas say so & , if one knows Puranas are the vedas in itself put for non dwijas & those who dont understnd vedas. Thus, in tht case I think latter sounds more apt. Secondly, as per ShreeVidyakrama, Indra is one of the 12 grt sadhaks,  thus maybe becoz of aikya wid Lalita, he got to be called as Parbrahm. There can be endless reasons. Like, while extolling a deity often they are called as Parbrahama. Thus, I think this 2 can be d reason.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views :) .

Answer (score 1):

> At the lower part of this earth there are seven places (caves or nether regions). Their diameter is one Ayuta Yojanas. In all the seasons, all sorts of enjoyments can be had at these places. **The ﬁrst is Atala; the second is Vitala. Next come in order :-- Sutala, Talâtala, Mahâtala. Rasâtala, and lastly (the seventh) the Pâtâla.** O Vipra!

> Nârâyana said : O Vipra! In the ﬁrst beautiful region **Atala**, the exceedingly haughty son of the Dânava Mâyâ, named Bala, is living.

> Now hear, the description of the second region Vitala.
> **Vitala** is situated below the earth. There the Bhagavân Bhava, worshipped by all the Devas, has assumed the name of Hâtakes’vara and is staying there coupled with Bhavânî

> Below Vitala is **Sutala**. It is reckoned as of some special importance. O Muni! The highly meritorious Bali, the son of Virochana lives here. The Bhagavân Vâsudeva, brought down this Bali into Sutala, for the welfare of Indra... O Devarsi! **Thus Bali, the Lord of Daityas, the highly respected and renowned in all the Lokas, is reigning in Sutala.**

> Nârâyana said : O Nârada! The cave lower down than Sutala is **Talâtala**! The Lord of Tripura, (the three cities) the great Mâyâ Dânava is the Ruler of this region.

> Next to this Talâtala is the most renowned **Mahâtala**. The sons of Kadru, the very angry Snakes, live here.

> Lower down this Mahâtala is **Rasâtala**. The Daityas, Dânavas and Pani Asuras live here. Besides these, there live the Nivâta Kavachas of the Hiranyapura city and the Asuras named Kâleyas, the enemies of the Devas.

> Lower down is **Pâtâla**, where live Vâsuki, the Chief of the
> snakes, and others named S’ankha, Kulika, S’veta, Dhananjaya,
> Mahâs’ankha, Dhritarâstra, S’ankhachûda, Kamvala, As’vatara, and Devopadattaka, all very angry, of wide hoods, and virulently poisonous.

> At the bottom of this Pâtâla, and at a distance of the thirty Yojanas; the Portion of Bhagavân (Ananta or Sesa) in the shape of the inﬁnite Darkness is reigning there.

Reference -

1. Srimad Devi Bhagavatam, 8th Skandha, Ch [18](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57306.html), [19](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57307.html), [20](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57308.html)